# Insert into from existing table?

Tags: sql

I know there's probably a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to remember how.

Basically, I have a table with 2 fields, ID1 and ID2. I want to find all fields with an id2 = 1, and insert another record into the table with that id1 and a different id2.

So the query to select all the fields that I want a new record for is:

```
select id1 from mytable where id2 = 1
```

And then for each of those I want to insert:

```
insert into mytable(id1, id2) values([this id1], 6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically just have to combine the two queries you've already written in a slightly different way:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id1, id2) 
SELECT id1, 6 FROM mytable WHERE id2 = 1
```

Comment: guess I'll accept this one cuz you beat us both by a minute or so :) thanks for responding so promptly. (will accept as soon as it allows)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for your purpose?

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id1, id2)
SELECT id, 6
FROM mytable
WHERE id2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. Just had the syntax wrong. (Would delete the question, but can't)

```
insert into mytable (id1, id2)
select id1, 6 from mytable where id2= 1
```

(I was struggling with syntax like this:

```
insert into mytable (id1, id2) 
values((SELECT id1 FROM mytable WHERE id2 = 1), 6)
```

and couldn't figure out how to rearrange it)

Comment: Precisely. But this is identical to the answer I posted a couple minutes before yours -- so you should accept one of them and leave the question here for others to find.

Comment: agreed, just mark @Cory's answer correct, since he actually answered before me, just in case someone need this in the future